# MySQL 5.7 issue with 16TB disk

Tags: mysql, partitioning, windows

(Repost from StackOverflow)

I have a MySQL 5.7 running on a Windows Server 2016 VM with two disks from a NAS: C:\ for system and D:\ for data (empty at start). I try to create a partitioned table:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `PROFILES`;
CREATE DATABASE `PROFILES` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;
use `PROFILES`;

CREATE TABLE PROFILES.ACQUISITION (
    Id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(id) (
       PARTITION p_MAXVALUE VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
       DATA DIRECTORY = 'D:\\MyDataBase'
);
```

Here's the issue:

- if D:\ has a capacity of 16TB (value found using dichotomy) or bellow, it works perfectly fine: the D:\MyDataBase\profiles directory is created, and the profiles#acquisition#p_maxvalue.ibd file is in there
- if D:\ has a capacity over 16TB, the D:\MyDataBase\profiles directory is created (OK), but the profiles#acquisition#p_maxvalue.ibd file is stored in the default MySQL Data directory\profiles, - on C:). No error message is written in the MySQL logs.

When looking at MySQL internal tables,

```
select * from information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES where name like '%profile%';
```

returns one row if D:\ is <=16TB, and nothing if >16TB.

Has anyone has an explaintation and/or a fix? Thanks in advance!

(Bye The way: this is not a `innodb_page_size` issue, as it is set to default 16K value, and is only related to the maximum size of the files, not to the disk capacity itself)

Comment: you might have found a bug, suggest reporting it on bugs.mysql.com.